# GestureRecognizer is not working for Tableview Dropdown dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` dropdown on clicking button you can find in below image. Here my problem is whenever if user wants to tap out side of tableView. that drop-down need to dismiss. below am using `UIScrollView`. I have tried with code

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)]; 
  tap.cancelsTouchesInView=NO;
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

but it's not working.

Here is the image

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: i forget to post image on top Please find the image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ixn.png

Comment: how about use `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Comment: i tried "- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event" but not working

Comment: this kind of view, i prefer to use another view below tableview then the background view handle touch action

Comment: set user userInteractionEnabled false to scrollview

Comment: and only this code is hard to tell.

Comment: @VijayenderVaddepally - change your subview from `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];` to `[yourscrollviewName addGestureRecognizer:tap];` and try once

Comment: i tried bro its not working @anbu.karthik

Comment: add  the break point and check once the method s called or not

Comment: can you shw the code of dismissKeyboard

Comment: -(void)dismissKeyboard{
 
    [_Tableobj  setHidden:YES];
}

Comment: what is _Tableobj?

Comment: please check the below answer i posted. i tried like that its working

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Add `UIGestureRecognizer` to `UIScrollView`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTableView)];

[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

In the method `dismissTableView`

```
-(void) dismissTableView 
{
    aTableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Where `aTableView` is object of your tableView.

And whenever you clicked on button make `aTableView.hidden = NO;`

Comment: Then add tap gesture recognizer to scroll view

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if the gesture is working on when you touch outside the tableview, i think it is not.The problem is your scroll view is eating all touch events. Try to add tap gesture on scroll view as it will definitely work. Like this.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: First try to disable all the gesture recognizers you added except the scroll view one and then see if it is working.

Comment: and also check user interaction is enable for both scroll view and view.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the answer.....

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

tap.delegate=self;

[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Used this `UIGestureDelegate` method...

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer )gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch )touch{

if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:_Tableobj]) 
{

    return NO;

}else{

    return YES;

}
```

Keyboard board dismiss method...

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard{


    [_Tableobj setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to add the tap gesture in your scroll view, not it's superview which also named `self.view`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     // hide your table view or resignFirstResponder of textfield

}
```